# How to dynamically add a query in crystal report and where condition

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

How to dynamically add a query in crystal report and where condition  to select record or column from multiple table and how to add field in crystal report

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "select * from tblStudentFees";
    ds = cc.ExecuteDataset(sql);

    ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Andorid_Class_App/ReportFees.rpt"));

    doc.SetDataSource(ds);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your DataSet to crystal reports as you're doing with any query result set, so taking your example you'd just alter the query as per your requirements:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "select * from tblStudentFees
                  join sometable on tblStudents.sometable_id = sometable.id
                  where sometable.value = somecriteria";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = cc.ExecuteDataset(sql);

    ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Andorid_Class_App/ReportFees.rpt"));

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
    CrystalReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataSources.Add(
    new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSetIdentifier", ds)
    );
}
```